# Python - Converting Months into Years - For Loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to convert months into years (range over 12 years) while keeping the end balance the same

This is what I have so far

```
initialBalance = 2000
monthlyIntrestRate = (6.25/12)/100
monthlyContribution = 200

counter = []
endBalance = initialBalance
for month in range(1, 216):   
    intrest = endBalance*monthlyIntrestRate
    endBalance = endBalance + intrest + monthlyContribution
    counter.append(endBalance)

print('The savings amount is $' + str(round(endBalance,2)))
```

Comment: Use a yearly interest rate and yearly contributions instead of a monthly rate and monthly contributions, and loop over 18 years instead of 216 months.  What is the actual problem here?

Comment: @JohnGordon you wouldn't get the same final result though, no ?

Comment: @JohnGordon Using this you get an endBalance of 85035.09, using your method you don't get that. As mentioned I need this endBalance to be the same

Comment: This sounds more like a [math.se] problem, figuring out the rate adjustment for yearly compounding instead of monthly compounding.

Comment: you asked nearly the same some days before, but with a little more input. To learn how to program you have to try harder. First Hint: Take this code and comment each line what you expect that line is for